# Changing values in JSON file through R

Tags: json, r

Is there a way to change values, or assign new variables in a json file and after give it back in the same format?

It can be used `rjson` pachage to get the json file in R in `data.frame` format but how to covert back this data.frame to json after my changes?

**EDIT**:
sample code:

json file:

```
{"__v":1,"_id":{"$oid":"559390f6fa76bc94285fa68a"},"accountId":6,"api":false,"countryCode":"no","countryName":"Norway","date":{"$date":"2015-07-01T07:04:22.265Z"},"partnerId":1,"query":{"search":[{"label":"skill","operator":"and","terms":["java"],"type":"required"}]},"terms":[{"$oid":"559390f6fa76bc94285fa68b"}],"time":19,"url":"eyJzZWFyY2giOlt7InRlcm1zIjpbImphdmEiXSwibGFiZWwiOiJza2lsbCIsInR5cGUiOiJyZXF1aXJlZCIsIm9wZXJhdG9yIjoiYW5kIn1dfQ","user":11}
{"__v":1,"_id":{"$oid":"5593910cfa76bc94285fa68d"},"accountId":6,"api":false,"countryCode":"se","countryName":"Sweden","date":{"$date":"2015-07-01T07:04:44.565Z"},"partnerId":1,"query":{"search":[{"label":"company","operator":"or","terms":["microsoft"],"type":"required"},{"label":"country","operator":"or","terms":["se"],"type":"required"}]},"terms":[{"$oid":"5593910cfa76bc94285fa68e"},{"$oid":"5593910cfa76bc94285fa68f"}],"time":98,"url":"eyJzZWFyY2giOlt7InRlcm1zIjpbIm1pY3Jvc29mdCJdLCJsYWJlbCI6ImNvbXBhbnkiLCJ0eXBlIjoicmVxdWlyZWQiLCJvcGVyYXRvciI6Im9yIn0seyJ0ZXJtcyI6WyJzZSJdLCJsYWJlbCI6ImNvdW50cnkiLCJ0eXBlIjoicmVxdWlyZWQiLCJvcGVyYXRvciI6Im9yIn1dfQ","user":13}
```

Code:

```
library('rjson')
c <- file(Usersfile,'r')
l <- readLines(c,-1L)
json <- lapply(X=l,fromJSON)
json[[1]]$countryName <- 'Jamaica'
result <- cat(toJSON(json))
```

Output(is one line and start with `[`:

```
[{"__v":1,"_id":{"$oid":"559390f6fa76bc94285fa68a"},"accountId":6,"api":false,"countryCode":"no","countryName":"Jamaica","date":{"$date":"2015-07-01T07:04:22.265Z"},"partnerId":1,"query":{"search":[{"label":"skill","operator":"and","terms":"java","type":"required"}]},"terms":[{"$oid":"559390f6fa76bc94285fa68b"}],"time":19,"url":"eyJzZWFyY2giOlt7InRlcm1zIjpbImphdmEiXSwibGFiZWwiOiJza2lsbCIsInR5cGUiOiJyZXF1aXJlZCIsIm9wZXJhdG9yIjoiYW5kIn1dfQ","user":11},{"__v":1,"_id":{"$oid":"5593910cfa76bc94285fa68d"},"accountId":6,"api":false,"countryCode":"se","countryName":"Sweden","date":{"$date":"2015-07-01T07:04:44.565Z"},"partnerId":1,"query":{"search":[{"label":"company","operator":"or","terms":"microsoft","type":"required"},{"label":"country","operator":"or","terms":"se","type":"required"}]},"terms":[{"$oid":"5593910cfa76bc94285fa68e"},{"$oid":"5593910cfa76bc94285fa68f"}],"time":98,"url":"eyJzZWFyY2giOlt7InRlcm1zIjpbIm1pY3Jvc29mdCJdLCJsYWJlbCI6ImNvbXBhbnkiLCJ0eXBlIjoicmVxdWlyZWQiLCJvcGVyYXRvciI6Im9yIn0seyJ0ZXJtcyI6WyJzZSJdLCJsYWJlbCI6ImNvdW50cnkiLCJ0eXBlIjoicmVxdWlyZWQiLCJvcGVyYXRvciI6Im9yIn1dfQ","user":13}]
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25550711/convert-data-frame-to-json

Answer (score 0):

[convert data frame to json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25550711/convert-data-frame-to-json)

So this question has already been answered in full here ^^^

Quick Summary ::

There are 2 options presented. 
(A) rjson library
import the library
use to the toJSON() method to create a JSON object. (Not exactly sure what the unname() function does... :p ).

(B) jsonlite library
import the jsonlite library
just use the toJSON() method (same as above, but with no modification).
cat() the above object.

Code examples are at that link. Hope this helps!

Comment: I have seen this post, but the json file doesnt have the same format as before.

Comment: @MpizosDimitris Could you post an example of the differences between the initial and final version of the JSON object?

Comment: just edit my asnwer. btw how can I write the output to a json file? What I am trying to do is just to output it in the console.